# Fire stored procedure on new connection

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Wondering if this is possible at all?

- On the SQL Server create a stored procedure
- This stored procedure gets fired when a new connection to the server is attempted.
- Stored procedure checks connection string of new connection and if connection string doesn't contain some required attribute it kills the connection.

This is to stop people with an old version of the product connection to a new database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out logon triggers. I think you could write your code in there and not have to really use a stored procedure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb326598%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: I ended up using something like this:   CREATE TRIGGER NoOldVersionLogin
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
 if  charindex('oldversionconnectionstringinfo', (SELECT
  sess.program_name as ApplicationName
 FROM
  sys.dm_exec_connections conn
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON
  conn.session_ID = sess.session_ID
 WHERE
  conn.session_ID = @@SPID)) = 0
    ROLLBACK;
END